# Complete Biosphere DNA Collection

Tags: technology, fauna, flora

So you have just come across a new life bearing planet with  organisms with Earth-like biology. You want to accomplish a complete biosphere analysis (sample collection)  in a timely manner. How would you accomplish this?

(The aliens from "The Day The Earth Stood Still" did this using glowing orbs)

Guidelines:

-Collect DNA (or whole organism) samples from 99% of the planet's life ( flora, fauna, microbes, etc.)

-Accomplish this task within 100-200 years

-What technology would you need to accomplish this? (Be realistic, using technologies we could create within the next few hundred years)

[Spherical Arks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KatFH.jpg)

Comment: Given we can't even agree on what constitutes a [species](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Species#Attempts_at_definition)...

Comment: On that time frame 'by hand' seems entirely possible if you have enough people able to go out and physically gather specimins. Already we have submarines and probes that can go to very extreme places. Lots of people, a few probes, insane levels of organization to not miss a spot, enough time, done.

Comment: This is an interesting question, but suitable answers could fill a list as long as your arm. Tighten up the criteria and we could have a good question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Collect soil.  Collect water.  We could do this now.**

DNA persists in the environment for a long, long time.  Researchers are studying extinct mammals and Neaderthals using DNA extracted from cave soil.

---

[No bones? No problem: DNA left in cave soils can reveal ancient human occupants](http://www.sciencemag.org/news/2017/04/no-bones-no-problem-dna-left-cave-soils-can-reveal-ancient-human-occupants)

> Scientists have known that DNA can survive in ancient sediments since
>   2003, when Eske Willerslev, an evolutionary geneticist at the
>   University of Copenhagen, sequenced the DNA of mammoths, horses, and
>   19 plant taxa from cores drawn from Siberian permafrost and temperate
>   caves.

---

Study ocean life by studying the water.

[DNA analysis of seawater detects 80% of fish species in just one day](https://phys.org/news/2017-01-dna-analysis-seawater-fish-species.html)

> A new solution to the survey issue has recently drawn attention:
>   environmental DNA metabarcoding, a method which can simultaneously
>   detect multiple species. This method identifies the fish species
>   through collection and analysis of DNA released by fish in seawater
>   (environmental DNA, or eDNA).

---

The microbiome is full of organisms that have never been seen or cultured.  You can tell them apart and count them by extracting DNA from soil.

[High diversity in DNA of soil bacteria.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/2317046)

> Our results show that the major part of DNA isolated from the
>   bacterial fraction of soil is very heterogeneous, with a C0t1/2 about
>   4,600, corresponding to about 4,000 completely different genomes of
>   standard soil bacteria.

A cool thing about this study - one fraction of the DNA did not correspond to known bacteria, and had different properties.  The researchers guess this fraction might represent bacteriophages.  This was published in 1990 - not cutting edge tech.

---

Your survey crew will draw transect lines across the face of this world and move along them, sampling in 3 dimensions as they go.  Along the line they will sample at the surface, they will sample the deep until it is too hot, and they will sample high until it is too cold.  DNA does not hide.  They will retrieve DNA from every species and many that have gone extinct.  You will need to be able to distinguish them.  You will name them by their DNA.

You could go do this with the technology we have now.  The bigger your crew, the faster the work will go.

Answer (score 0):

Some kind of scan or nanotechnology.

Either this is done at a distance, or its something that would need to be automated and dispersed through the target.

There's no way to do this manually. And your collection mechanism would need to be able to brave the various extreme regions (e.g. deep sea beds).

I'd go with some kind of high-definition scanning technology or swarms of nanobots. The latter is more realistic, IMO.